# How to add data to returned ActiveRecord query records

Tags: arrays, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I'm doing a simple query to a database table to send off to an external service, but I need to add an element to each of the returned records before I do so.

**app.rb**

```
get "/:task/:account_id/contacts" do
  @contacts = Contact.where("Account = ?", params[:account_id])

  @contacts.to_json
end
```

Provides me the data I need formatted as

```
[{"Name":"Charlie Spencer","sfid":"a014100000AYi2ZABG","id":29,"Account":"a054100000FsEA8AAN"},{"Name":"Philip Leak","sfid":"a014100000AYi3PCHZ","id":48,"Account":"a054100000FsEA8AAN"}]
```

But I need to add the provided task within the route to the results before sending it off via json as such:

```
[{"Name":"Charlie Spencer","sfid":"a014100000AYi2ZABG","id":29,"Account":"a054100000FsEA8AAN","Task":"a014100000AYiWMCC1"},{"Name":"Philip Leak","sfid":"a014100000AYi3PCHZ","id":48,"Account":"a054100000FsEA8AAN","Task":"a014100000AYiWMCC1"}]
```

How do I iterate over the returned results before sending it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one. `map` method to transform your result, `attributes` method to have an hash with fields and values and `merge` method to add the task.

```
get "/:task/:account_id/contacts" do
  @contacts = Contact.where("Account = ?", params[:account_id]).map do |c|
    c.attributes.merge("Task": params[:task])
  end

  @contacts.to_json
end
```